# TensorflowJs shape increase while training

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to teach my model on tensorflow to classify images but cannot reach any suitable effect.

For base im generating main model.json on https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image. Then i go and write code

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs')
const  tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const feature_file = "image3.jpg"//human
const feature_file2 = "imgs/3.jpg"//not human

const sharp = require('sharp');
const x = 224
const y = 224
const height = x
const width = y

f()
async function f(){
    const imageBuffer = await fs.readFile(feature_file);
const tensorFeature = tfnode.node.decodeImage( await sharp(imageBuffer).resize(x, y).toBuffer()) // create a tensor for the image
const imageBuffer2 = await fs.readFile(feature_file2);
const tensorFeature2 = tfnode.node.decodeImage( await sharp(imageBuffer2).resize(x, y).toBuffer()) // create a tensor for the image

labelArray = ['Class 1', 'Class 2'] // maybe 0 for dog, 1 for cat and 2 for birds
tensorFeatures = tf.stack([tensorFeature, tensorFeature2])
tensorLabels = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(labelArray, 'int32'),2);
    // console.log(tensorFeatures)
    // console.log(tensorLabels)
    
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://model4//model.json')    
    model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: tf.train.adam(1e-3), metrics: ['accuracy']});
    model.summary()
    model.fit(tensorFeatures, tensorLabels, {
        epochs: 12,
        batchSize:1
    }).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res)
      })
    model.save(`file://model3`)
```

So problem is if i generated in teachable machine 2 classes and trying to add 3th one, it asks that input shape must be [, 2].
So i add

```
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3, activation: 'softmax'}));
```

And change `tensorLabels = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(labelArray, 'int32'),2);`
to `tensorLabels = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(labelArray, 'int32'),3);`

But after all of this operations my model classifies images fully wrongly. Is any way available to do some images training in Node.js tensorflow?
I'm trying to do it second week and have no idea.

Comment: Did you train the model with the 3 classes ?

Comment: hello, not, i trained model only with 2 classes in teachable machine and tried manualy to add third class, which was my fail. I don't realy understand how to make some simple teachable machine.

Comment: If you want to predict with three classes, you need to train with three classes, you cannot load a model trained with 2 classes and predict with three classes. It will not work

Comment: yes, i want to load model trained with 2 classes and train him to predict 3 classes, instead of basic 2. And only AFTER training 3 classes - predicting

Comment: It will be easier that you add all your classes right at the beginning. It will be simpler